# Is there a way to set the default line ending for GitHub Copilot?

Tags: line-endings, github-copilot

I am trying out GitHub Copilot on a project that uses CRLF for all line endings. Copilot often suggests other line endings (CR or LF). Is there a way to configure or tell Copilot to only use a certain line ending?